# awk to list grand total of report

Tags: bash, awk

Hi i am trying to list the grand total of the report.
have tried to list the total. but am not sure what code to use to combine the `total salaried` and `total hourly` together from awk

please advise

result:

```
Salaried:
Frank    $2333
Mary     $1111

Total salaried: $3444
Hourly:
Chris     $122

Total Hourly:122
----------------------
Grand Total: $3566
```

.txt file :

sequence as followed : [id], [name],[title],[phone],[type],[pay]

```
3,Frank,CFO,91111453,Salaried,2333
1,Mary,CEO,93424222,Salaried,1111
5,John,Sales user,9321312,Commission,9999
7,Chris,Admin,98888753,Hourly,122
```

code :

```
     #salaried
        awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "Salaried"} $5=="Salaried"{salaried+=$6; printf "%s\t\t\t\t$%s\n", $2, $6} END {printf "Total salaried payroll: \t$%s", salaried}' $PAYROLL
       echo
       echo
       #hourly
       awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "Hourly"} $5=="Hourly"{hourly+=$6; printf "%s\t\t\t\t$%s\n", $2, $6} END {printf "Total Hourly payroll: \t\t$%s", hourly}' $PAYROLL
       echo
       echo "Grand total:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk like this;

```
awk -F, '{t[$5]+=$6} END{for (i in t) print i, t[i]}' file
Hourly 122
Commission 9999
Salaried 3444
```

**For frand total:**

```
awk -F, '{t[$5]+=$6} END{for (i in t) {sum+=t[i]; print i, t[i]} print "Grand Total: " sum}' file
Hourly 122
Commission 9999
Salaried 3444
Grand Total: 13565
```

Comment: i've got it to list Hourly 122,
Commission 9999,
Salaried 3444 accordingly, now im stuck with adding them together to form Grand Total as this does not have any variable to add

Comment: hi, i've got more questions, confused . need to printout a report with the count of how many employee has $1000 pay or less. anyone know/?

Comment: @Alien: I suggest creating a new question with your specific problem to get better answers.